# How to get all directories inside given directory that contains file with specific name

Tags: java, file, io

I have program where input parameter is name of directory. 
I need to get all subdirectories of this directory, which contains specially named file (if file not present, skip), other files and directories must be ignored. Is there simple way to achieve this? 
I found  `DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY` used while `file.listFiles` method is called, but it is not what i need. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered similar question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20680556/3115098

You have to implement FileFilter to match specific requirements for your folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Thanks. I'll accept this answer as soon as I can.